# A step by step small app creation guide in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a step to step tutorial to make an app, not so complex in Ruby, so students can do it. By now, i have only medium-big examples that i have developed for companies some years ago,but they require extra knowledge as i used diff frameworks and libraries and i want something that can be done only with the ruby interpreter itself.

A well commented app will be good as well as i can make some step-to-step guide based on that, and yea maybe I can do one but the thing is that im running out of time, and i haven't used ruby in like 1.5-2years, so as i said im looking for something not so complex and not so big, 200 , 300, 400, or 500 lines of code is ok

Could be anything, like administration or managing purpose like idk, a script that generates word documents for certain department. A script that reads a .txt or .doc and do something with that, idk.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: really, you need to try something called google or github or sourceforge.......

Comment: i've tried but i have only found medium-big examples and using rails or tk or extra stuff

Answer (score 2):

It's not an app really, but it's smallish, it's Ruby, it's sort of a game, and it's fun. http://github.com/ryanb/ruby-warrior

Comment: To accompany Ruby Warrior
http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/ruby-warrior-walkthrough-part-1